# Measuring internet link downtime

Tags: internet

My ISP is known for having frequent downtimes. I use a ubuntu 10.04 based server as a primary gateway for my NAT network. I am looking for a tool or script that will measure the duration of each down time.

Comment: Hopefully you'll be giving this information to your ISP and complaining. I've had my fair share of expensive under-par ISP service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. You could use the [ping](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aPing) plug-in for [collectd](http://collectd.org/) to monitor ping time from your ubuntu gateway to some selected internet hosts.
2. If your router supports [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol), You could use [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) to monitor traffic on the router interfaces.
3. You could install [smtpd](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Snmpd) on your ubuntu gateway and use mrtg to monitor the gateway interfaces.
4. Last, but not least, you could use [snmp collectd plug-in](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aSNMP) to monitor directly the uptime on your router wan interface (but this requires some basic snmp knowledge).